# function of 'As' in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, usage, as

> Chosen not **as** much for his charm, or lack thereof, **as** for his minatory appearance, the singer's bodyguard proved to be an effective deterrent for many autograph-seekers.

What is the role of 'as' in this sentence? For me, it seems also cool not to use 'as', like

> Chosen not for his charm, or lack thereof, but for his minatory appearance,

Comment: You're right, the meaning is roughly the same. But the sentence itself is a bit incoherent—"Chosen not for... the _lack of charm_, but for his _minatory appearance_..." is a rather strange antithesis since both notions are in a sense overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the role of 'as' in this sentence?

It is a correlative conjunction.

References:
[yourdictionary.com](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/correlative-conjunctions.html)
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar))

These include as/as, as much/as, not/but, and others.

> Chosen (not) **as much** for his charm **as** for his minatory appearance.
>
> Chosen **not** for his charm **but** for his minatory appearance.

"Not/but" is presenting a stark contrast. "As/as" is more of a comparison. So, the meanings are a bit different, however not hugely different. Either could be used here.